# Cannot resolve file 'img.jpg'. intellij idea

Tags: html, image, intellij-idea

don't see the image. How can fix error? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcdrx.jpg)
Cannot resolve file 'img.jpg'.
This inspection checks unresolved file references in HTML

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Where is `img.jpg` file in the project? It should reside next to `index.html` you are trying to reference it from.

Answer (score 1):

for inline css you used attribute style in open t
used this code:

`<body style="background:url(img.jpg)">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the background image with inline styles, it would be written like this:

```
<body style="background: url(img.jpg);">
```

Or more specifically, if you only want to change the background image and not unset all other background properties:

```
<body style="background-image: url(img.jpg);">
```